# What about the HUM for a finite-dimensional system?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, control-theory

We consider the finite-dimensional system
\begin{equation}\begin{cases}y'(t)=Ay(t)+Bv,\ t\in (0,T)\\ y(0)=y^0\end{cases}\end{equation}
Where $v$ is the control, $A\in Mat(N\times N); B\in Mat(N\times N)$ and $y^0\in \mathbb{R}^N$.

This problem is exact controllable if for any fixed $y^1\in\mathbb{R}^N; y^0\in\mathbb{R}^N$, there exists a control $v\in \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $y(T)=y^1$.

There are many ways to get the exact controllability of this problem. For examples: Kalman rank condition; (HUM): Observability inequality, Uniqueness continuation,....

We have read a paper which the author gave the following way:

"If $y^0=0$ then the finite-dimensional problem is exactly controllable if for $f\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and any $v\in \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $<y(T),f>=0$ then $f\equiv 0$."

So, in the case $y^0\neq 0$, What is the similar?

Comment: I didn't quite understand the condition. But generally if $y^0 \neq 0$, you can use $y(T) - e^{AT} y^0$, that is ignoring the homogenous part as it has nothing to do with controllability.

Comment: Can you explain about your opinion?

Comment: Now, I am wondering that the above condition is true or fail?